# How to build CPAN Perl Module 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: perl, build, cpan

I'm attempting to build a CPAN module, and I require both the 32 and 64-bit versions of this module for use on different machines. I'm not familiar with the way to build 32 and 64 bit versions of modules. I've attempted to download the pre-built module from ActivePerl PPM, but unfortunately I don't have the funds to purchase an enterprise license required for the compiled 64-bit modules.

My question is: Can I simply download the module source from CPAN, build it on a 32-bit machine for the 32-bit version, and build the same module on a 64-bit PC for the 64-bit version?

I would appreciate any assistance with this.

Thank You,

Russ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, though I'd only do that if I didn't want to use `cpan` for some reason.

Using the standard Perl installers, the module is first installed into a `blib` directory inside the build directory by `make` or `Build`. These are the files that are tested by `make test` or `Build test`, and these are the files that are installed by `make install` or `Build install`.

If you have two sufficiently similar machines, you can build the module on one machine, and install it on another from the files in `blib`. That's what `ppm` does.

Note that you can easily create a ppd for use by ppm by following [these instructions](http://jenda.krynicky.cz/perl/PPM.html).

Comment: If I use this approach, and take the files from the blib directory, will I have to perform this twice (once on a 32-bit machine and once on a 64-bit machine) to have both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions?

Comment: There's nothing similar about a 32-bit and 64-bit Perl. Twice if it has arch-dependent features.

Comment: No, I don't believe it has architecture dependent features. The package is the DBD-ODBC module. I have downloaded the source, I'm unsure about how to build both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Comment: Most definitely architecture dependent. It's an interface to an external driver (i.e. it links to a DLL).